# Printing array elements at random until all elements have been printed

Tags: java, arrays, random, for-loop, printing

I'm trying to create a method that takes in 3 int arrays and prints out one element from each array until all the elements of all three arrays have been printed at least once. The first array has 10 elements, the second has 7, and the third has 2. The elements are selected and printed at random. Any help would be appreciated. The idea is to see how many iterations it would take to print out all the elements at least once. I don't know the conditions to set for 
a large scale iteration like this. My code so far (with just one array as a parameter):

```
import java.util.*;

public class calculateAverage{

  private static int[] x = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  private static int[] y = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
  private static int[] z = new int[]{1,2};



  public static void main(String[] args){    
    calculate(x);

  }

  public static void calculate(int a[]){
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0;i < a.length; i++){
      System.out.print(a[random.nextInt(a.length)] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

code output:
7 2 4 1 8 10 3 10 7 3

Comment: Depends on the seed of randomizer. Same seed = same numbers each time.

Comment: (i) join all the arrays in one collection (ii) shuffle (iii) print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for one array:

```
public static int calculate(int a[]){
    Random random = new Random();
    HashSet<Integer> remaining = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        remaining.add(i);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (!remaining.isEmpty()) {
        int index = random.nextInt(a.length);
        System.out.print(a[index] + " ");
        remaining.remove(index);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Finished after " + i + " iterations.");
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're awesome, this is it, thanks heaps. But how would you implement it with 3 arrays. I want to call this method a couple number of times to determine the average least amount of iterations it would take to print all the elements of all the arrays.

Comment: I just reviewed your code again. No further alterations are needed. I just realized that only the array with the most elements is needed as it will determine the overall number of iterations needed. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection like `Set` to keep track of indexes that were already picked. Each time you generate a random number you would first check if it already exist in the Set. If not, print the value in array and add the index number to the set.

Your loop would end when size of that set equals size of the array.

Comment: The problem is that I need each array element to be picked and then replaced so that it has the same chance as the other elements to be picked again. And to be honest, I don't really know how to use Set, could you give an example by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[] = {4, 6, 3, 2, 9, 1, 5};        
Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
int counter = 0;
Random rand = new Random();
while(set.size() != a.length){
    set.add(a[rand.nextInt(a.length)]);
    counter ++;
}
System.out.println("Total Iterations : "+counter);
return counter;
```